# What were Prince Sultan's duties in STS-51-G?

Tags: space-shuttle, astronauts

[Prince Sultan bin Salman Al Saud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_bin_Salman_bin_Abdulaziz_Al_Saud) was the first (and so far only) Saudi astronaut, and was included in the crew of [STS-51-G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-51-G) as a payload specialist representing [Arabsat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Satellite_Communications_Organization). Does that mean his role was strictly honorary and he had no explicit function within the mission (somewhat like the Teacher in Space Project)?

In essence, what were his duties aboard the mission as a payload specialist?

Comment: The info [here](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=27828.75) seems to imply that Prince Sultan had a working knowledge of the Arabsat satellite deployment.

Comment: @called2voyage - That looks like an answer to me. Or at least part of one.

Comment: [The Space Above Us Podcast](http://thespaceabove.us) covered STS-51G recently (episode 85, 11 July 2019); I haven't listened to the episode yet, but it may have some information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's important to note that Al-Saud (the way his name was listed in his NASA [bio](https://web.archive.org/web/20040414131459/http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/al-saud.html), now gone down the memory hole like most of jsc.nasa.gov) paid for his ticket.

Back in those days of flying commercial payloads on the Shuttle, it was possible to pay for a payload specialist seat as part of "Standard Launch Services".

[image]

(emphasis mine, scanned from *[STS Customer Accomodations JSC-21000-HBK](https://archive.org/download/jsc-21000-hbk-sts-customer-accomodations-a-handbook-for-space-shuttle-users/JSC-21000-HBK_STS_Customer_Accomodations_A_Handbook_for_Space_Shuttle_Users.pdf)*)

See also [Rodolfo Neri Vela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodolfo_Neri_Vela) of Mexico who flew as a payload specialist when the Mexican communications satellite [MORELOS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morelos_Satellite_System) was launched from STS-61B.

Their countries paid for the payload, which included the payload specialist seat, and got to pick who flew.

What they actually did on the flight was of secondary importance. Unfortunately, these missions flew too long ago to have their flight plans posted online, which would be the definite answer of what each crewperson did.

Note that [Spacefacts](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-51g.htm) states

> Sultan Salman Al-Saud, the Saudi Arabian payload specialist was not
> involved in the deployment activities of Arabsat.

but goes on to say

> Sultan Salman Al-Saud, the Saudi Arabian Arabsat payload specialist,
> took part in four scientific investigations: Earth Observation, Phase
> Separation, Ionized Gas and French Postural Experiments. Salman
> Al-Saud photographed Saudi Arabia during Discovery's daylight passes
> over its southwestern region with a 70 mm camera from orbit. The
> photographs were be studied by Saudi scientists at the research
> institute, the University of Petroleum and Minerals in Dhahran, Saudi
> Arabia. They also were compared with previous data from multispectral
> scanner, thematic mapper and radar images (SIR-A and SIR-B). Analysis
> covered geological features, sand dune morphology, hydrogeological
> features, turbidity in the Red Sea, urban areas and forestry.
>
> In
> another experiment, two liquids which do not mix on Earth were studied
> in microgravity. They were referred to as "phases." Using Phase
> Separation Experiment hardware developed at the NASA Marshall Space
> Flight Center, Salman Al-Saud placed various concentrations of Saudi,
> Kuwaiti and Algerian oils mixed with water in a hand-held, transparent
> Plexiglas container with 15 chambers, each having a small metal mixing
> ball. He shaked the container and mount it in front of a fluorescent
> light, then photograph the separation and record his observations [*sic*].
>
> The
> Ionized Gas Experiment (ICE) required that Sultan Salman Al-Saud,
> using the Orbiter Discovery's TV cameras, recorded thruster firings in
> specified configurations to study the mechanics of thruster plumes and
> the degree off Ionization produced. This experiment was part of a
> Saudi Arabian student Ph.D. thesis at Stanford University. Purpose was
> to assess the thruster plumes effect on operations measurements and
> communications associated with space vehicles. The data obtained also
> were analyzed at the university of petroleum and Minerals for a better
> understanding of the impact of gas particles on solid surfaces. Salman
> Al-Saud also photographed the Arabsat satellite's rocket engine
> firing.
>
> Salman Al-Saud assisted French payload specialist Patrick
> Baudry in the postural Experiment on the adaptation mechanism of the
> sensory motor activities. This included posture stabilization and
> orientation and the role of vision in posture control and reflex
> mechanisms that stabilize the retina. Requiring about 3 hours, the
> experiment was performed before, at the beginning, during the middle
> and last day of flight two times a day.

Answer (score 5):

I would stay away from terms and sayings such as "honorary" and "no explicit function" -- especially when you are talking about Christa McAuliffe.  It's insulting.

Having said that, there is a history of sending astronauts into space for indirect purposes.  Early astronauts were really not required for the mission other than to demonstrate survivability -- far from an "honorary" role...  McAuliffe's purpose was perfectly in line with the overall mission of NASA to build a scientific/technical American workforce by inspiring school children.  While the appropriateness of that mission for a government agency is subject to debate, her role in it is not.

Finally, if you are going to create a list like this, you probably should include [Jake Garn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jake_Garn).  Even he managed to provide a data point on space sickness...

So, to answer your question directly, no.

Comment: If I have shown any disrespect to the late Christa McAuliffe I humbly apologize. The Challenger tragedy traumatized me as a child, and I hold her memory sacred. Still, you've answered the question as if it had been centered around *her* involvement, rather than Prince Sultan's.

Comment: You answered your own question -- he was representing Arabsat.

Comment: And that was all? No other function?

Comment: "...that was all?"  It was one of the primary payloads you know...  Getting it deployed as more than an honorary function...

Comment: That's the crux of the question. What does that mean? Did he do the actual deployment? Did he simply supervise? Did he just do a ceremonial pulling-of-the-switch as a representative of the owners?

Comment: @Erik Your answer is incomplete given the rewording of the OP.

Comment: @called2voyage - no.  His duties were to be a Payload Specialist.  It is as if the OP were to ask if the Commander or Pilot had any explicit functions.  It's a nonsensical question.  Now, a good rewording would be to ask "what are the duties of a Payload Specialist?" -- but that would be leading the witness...

Comment: @Erik From the OP: "In essence, what were his duties aboard the mission **as a payload specialist**?"

Comment: I would like to know why you just made 8 rollbacks to this answer.